# What is good practice when u create a method whose parameter contains 2 objects but it only changes 1

Tags: c#

for example:

```
          void FilterA(Hashset<T> blackList, List<T> myList)
          {
            blackList.UnionWith(myList);
          }
```

I don't know if there would be some good coding styles that separates `blackList` and `myList` apart. Or is it necessary at all?

Comment: You need to put more care and effort into your code examples. At the very least write valid C# syntax that will actually compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't `List<T>` specific members, you could use a non-mutable interface instead. `IEnumerable<T>` is a good candidate.

Answer (score 7):

In terms of good practice - in your specific case, I would just leave this method out.  Implementing a method that just wraps a single framework method (`HashSet<T>.UnionWith`) is effectively doing nothing but obscuring code.

However, in general, I think documentation and naming is the key.  If your method name was more clear, it would be obvious.  Consider this method- `FilterA` actually suggests you're "filtering" the collection, not adding items to it based on the second collection.

Also, using an appropriate interface, such as `IEnumerable<T>`, instead of passing a concrete class (`List<T>`) can help differentiate things.  This is especially true if you pass `IEnumerable<T>`, as this is an interface that does not expose any edit operations.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like: `void FilterA(hashset<t> blacklist,IEnumerable<t> mylist>`. It's obvious that IEnumerables can't be modified.

But I think the most important things here are the names of a function and variables. It should be clear from their names what the function does.

Answer (score 2):

You can use IEnumerable for the second parameter.

```
void FilterA<T>(HashSet<T> blacklist, List<T> mylist)
{
    blacklist.UnionWith(mylist);
}
```

There's no direct equivalent to the C/C++ const parameter modifier.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to change mylist right? I suggest using this:

```
void FilterA<T>(HashSet<T> blacklist, IEnumerable<T> mylist)
{
    blacklist.UnionWith(mylist);
}
```